# Layout for Android ListView item like Twitter

Tags: android

As you already know, in Twiiter application,  twitt content stays in the right hand side of the Username, and in second line, the twitt content stays back to the left of the parent layout.
(which is similar to the Listview item's layout of Facebook Application)

My problem is the username and twitt content **belong to 2 different columns** :(

Could you please tell me the way to fix the problem?

Comment: You may wish to consider adding a screenshot or diagram or something to explain what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with a `RelativeLayout`?

Twitt `TextView` should have `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_name`.

You can also use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to see how they did it.
It might be illegal to do it, thought.